# Column width as given input

Tags: c, loops

In this code I try to print stars as many as given 9 numbers and try to create columns as given width. I'm a newbie so I can't use any fancy methods.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pm(int n, char c, int w)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < w; j++)
            printf("%c", c);
            printf("\n");
            printf("+------");
            printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

    int i;
    int width;
    int number = 9;
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9;

    printf("Enter 9 numbers (all less than 50):\n|1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9|\n");
    printf("|-----------------|\n ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6, &n7, &n8, &n9);

    printf("\nEnter the width of the charts (1, 3, 5 or 7):");
    scanf("%d", &width);

    pm(n1, '*', width);
    pm(n2, '*', width);
    pm(n3, '*', width);
    pm(n4, '*', width);
    pm(n5, '*', width);
    pm(n6, '*', width);
    pm(n7, '*', width);
    pm(n8, '*', width);
    pm(n9, '*', width);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

For example when the user enters 1-2-3-3-3-3-3-3-3 and 3 width; the output is:

```
***
+------
******
+------
********
+------
********
+------...
```

I want it to be:

```
*
*
*
+-------
**
**
**
+-------
```

I hope you get the idea.
I know the code is a mess but I just want to finish the code then i can arrange something better.

Comment: Did you get the license plate of the guy that stole your tab-key?

Comment: I'm still unclear what you are asking for?

Comment: Just pic one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style (perhaps better **not** gnu)

Comment: Thanks for solving my main problem guys, really, i appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some time to format your code properly (or use an editor that does it), you'll understand how it works better when you do so. Your code is:

```
void pm(int n, char c, int w){
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < w; j++)
      printf("%c", c);

  printf("\n");
  printf("+------");
  printf("\n");
}
```

So it prints `c` `n*w` times, then one newline character, then the separator and newline again.

To do what you want, you need something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < w; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("%c", c);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
printf("+------\n");
```

Notice the added `{}` blocks, to mark each `for` loop's scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I used your code but it prints
***
------
***
------
... With line skips of course.

Comment: Ah, the `n` and `w` are swapped. Try exchanging them.

Comment: Yes that seems to work well.  But it prints +------ with every star line. *+------*+------*+-------... Like that

Comment: @HalilM: fixed that detail. I suggest you take some time actually trying to understand what is going on/what the code does, you should have been able to fix that one yourself very easily. Also compile your code with all warnings enabled and fix all the problems the compiler will highlight.

Comment: Yep I just wrote that before you edited your answer. This works like charm. Thank you again :)

Comment: And BTW I still try to understand C language behavior. I used Java like 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **new line separator** after printing `char` 'c' in the function `pm`.

Try: `printf("%c\n", c);` instead of `printf("%c", c);`

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately your code prints all stars vertically.

Comment: isn't that what you asked? you demonstrated it vertically in the "I want it to be" section.

Comment: No, but I am going to need your code for later parts thanks :) (In the vertical graph part)